# htaccess problem not being able to overwrite previous rules

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

so guys, what i need to do is:

whenever someone ask for this url:

dev.site.com/noticias/id/tittle-for-the-news

( dev.site.com/noticias/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/ )

it needs to get this:

dev.site.com/noticias/?_escaped_fragment_noticias=id/tittle-for-the-news

so i go ahead and set this function (i've done some googlign for this but not quite sure if its ok)

```
function add_url_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_rule('noticias/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/', 'noticias/?_escaped_fragment_=noticias=/$1/$2', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_url_rewrite' );
```

but ofcoruse, this didnt work at all and that's why im here trying to find out.. how do i do an .htaccess rewrite rule for wordspress.

thanks in advance!

Comment: did you flush rewrite rules? It's not enough to add a rewrite rule, the ruleset needs recreating in the database afterwards

Comment: in the data base?? what? its only some htaccess settings. i m very confuse.....

Comment: regardless of whether it's an internal or external rule, if you don't flush rewrite rules nothing will happen.